# Is there any better way to round down values to different decimals?

Tags: javascript

I have a trading bot that is required to place orders according to the algorithm.
But the problem is in the rounding of asset sell orders. For example, if I have 820.9 units (coinbalance) of assets and I want to sell them. I have some rounding problem. Exchange only allows certain amount of decimals for asset.

```
lotDecimal=parseInt(countDecimals(data.minQty)); minQty=parseFloat(data.minQty)
```

Exchange gives me the minQty parameter, let's say for this case 1, and script counts decimals. For this example decimals would be 0. (For some cases minQty can be 0.1 => Decimal 1 and etc., so you can't just round to 0 decimals all the time)

As you can see, I can't just make

```
coinbalance.toFixed(lotDecimal)
```

As it will give me the value 821 (more than I can place for sale), so I need to round it down, so I came up with this:

```
coinbalance = (Math.floor(coinBalance/minQty)*minQty).toFixed(lotDecimal)
```

Is there any better way to solve it? But this thing works, or I am missing something?

Comment: That's the popular way for doing it and exactly how I would do it.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: What about just getting the remainder of dividing the `coinBalance` by the `minQty`, and subtracting it from the  `coinBalance`? Something like this: `coinBalance - (coinBalance % minQty)`